# Need 'return to main menu' feature in my C++ code

Tags: c++

I have created a C++ program. In this I have added many options for a user.
But in every choice I need to add a function from which a user can either choose to exit the program or can return to the main menu depending upon his choice. So can i have help in my coding.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
clrscr();
int choice,p_card;
char text0,text1;
cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t   \"Welcome to Zinc hospital\"\n\n\n";
cout<<"\tMENU\n";
cout<<"\n\n1. Emergency treatment\n\n";
cout<<"2. Common treatment\n\n";
cout<<"3. Regular checkups\n\n";
cout<<"4. Get appointment\n\n";
cout<<"5. Consult specialist\n\n";
cout<<"6. Pay due amount\n\n";
cout<<"7. Log in for new patient card\n\n";
cout<<"8. For suggestions, feedbacks and register complains\n\n";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tChoice______";
cin>>choice;
    clrscr();
      if(choice==1)
      {
      int e_choice;
      cout<<"\n\n\n  Enter the type of emergency";
      cout<<"\n\n1. Accidental case";
      cout<<"\n\n2. Heavy injury case";
      cout<<"\n\n3. Delicate organ injury\n\n";
      cout<<"4. Any other\n\n";
      cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEmergency choice____";
      cin>>e_choice;
      if(e_choice==4)
      {
      cout<<"Please specify the type of emergency ";
      cin>>text0;
      }
      cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\t      \"EMERGENCY DECLARED\"\n\n\t  \'Please quickly proceed to the operation theatre with patient\'";
      }
      if(choice==2)
      {
      cout<<"\n\nEnter the patient card number\n\n\t";
      cout<<"\t\t\tCard No.______";
      cin>>p_card;
      cout<<"\n\n\t\t\tYour card has been recognized succesfully.";
      cout<<"\n\n\nNow enter the specific treatment to be provided___";
      cin>>text0;
      cout<<"\n\n\n\n     \t\t\tDATA recorded succesfully";
      cout<<"\n\nYour card has been charged $10.\n\n\n\n      Please proceed to counter to get the room no. and wait list serial.";
      }
      else if(choice==3)
      {
      cout<<"";//Under construction
      }
      else if(choice==4)
      {
      cout<<"";//Under construction
      }
      else if(choice==5)
      {
      cout<<"";//Under construction
      }
      else if(choice==6)
      {
      cout<<"";//Under construction
      }
      else if(choice==7)
      {
      cout<<"";//Under construction
      }
      else if(choice==8)
      {
      cout<<"";//Under construction
      }
      else if(choice!=1&&choice!=2&&choice!=3&&choice!=4&&choice!=5&&choice!=6&&choice!=7&&choice!=8)
      {
      cout<<"Invalid choice inputed";
      cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t@Domain ERROR";
      }
getch();
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place where people write features for you for free.

Comment: means.... u cant help me!!

Comment: No, that's not what it means. I could resolve this for you, if I wanted to. Nice try though.

Comment: Please help me I m a student, and i need a litle help from you in my project.. I have around completed it. but I don't know how to add Return to menu function into it. I would be grateful to your help.

Comment: You are in the wrong place. This is not a personal helpdesk. You should ask a question about a programming language, that might help someone else. Please visit the Help Centre to find out what this site is about.

Comment: If you need help with a school project, you should ask your teachers. That's what they are there for!

Comment: ok I will.... but plz do note that I have wasted a lot of time in writing this program using 4 spaces. Instead help me and i will remove my question from here. I have to submit it tomorrow. I know its not personal helpdesk,  still please help me out

Comment: "I know I'm in the wrong place, but help me anyway. Because I left it until the last moment. Also I spent 30 seconds indenting the code by hand so I deserve it." Sorry, no.

Comment: Also you could have just pressed the "indent code" button to do it in a heartbeat. Or, in your editor, Select All, press tab...

Comment: Use a freestanding function to process the submenu.  The function will return (to the main menu) after the submenu is processed.

Comment: See also `switch` statement.  Much cleaner than an `if-else-if` ladder.

Comment: ok thanks.. so atlast u arn't helping me , right??

Comment: Thanks Thomas. You are a real helping hand

Comment: Research "state machines". Here's a starting point: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup table (one of many solutions).

```
typedef (void) (P_Function)(void);

struct Menu_Entry
{
  unsigned int  selection_number;
  const char *  text;
  P_Function    p_processing_function;
};

void Process_Emergency_Treatment(void);
void Process_Common_Treatment(void);

Menu_Entry main_menu[] = 
{
  {1, "Emergency Treatment", Process_Emergency_Treatment},
  {2, "Common Treatment", Process_Common_Treatment},
};
static const unsigned int quantity_menu_items =
  sizeof(main_menu) / sizeof(main_menu[0]);

// ...
unsigned int selection;
std::cout << "Enter selection: ";
std::cin >> selection;
unsigned int index = 0U;
for (index = 0U; index < quantity_menu_items; ++index)
{
  if (main_menu[index].selection_number == selection)
  {
    main_menu[index].p_processing_function(); // Execute the command processor.
    break;
  }
}
if (index >= quantity_menu_items)
{
  std::cout << "\nInvalid selection, try again.\n";
}
```

A nice advantage to the lookup table is that when you want to add items to the menu, add an entry into table.  Also, you only need to test the search loop once.  Adding more entries to the table doesn't effect the execution of the search loop.

**Edit 1:  Fundamental menu algorithm**
The fundamental algorithm can look like this:

```
bool selection_is_valid = false;
while (!selection_is_valid)
{
  Print_Menu();
  unsigned int selection = 0U;
  std::cout << "Enter selection: ";
  std::cin >> selection;
  if (select >= MAXIMUM_CHOICES)
  {
    selection_is_valid = false;
  }
  else
  {
     Process_Menu_Item(selection);
     selection_is_valid = true;
  }
}
```

With a little skill you can modify the above algorithm to display until an "exist selection" is pressed.